# I have installed Xdebug but it does not debug in VS Code and shows nothing in call stack

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, debugging, xampp, xdebug

I have tried many ways to solve this problem but nothing works. Here is my `php.ini` file code:

```ini
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

And I have also tried `xdebug.profiler_enable=on` but but both have this problem when I run `php -v` in CMD :

> Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)

Here is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\todoxampp\\todo_db.php",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug 2 (Legacy)",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script with Xdebug 2 (Legacy)",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.remote_enable=yes",
                "-dxdebug.remote_autostart=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "remote_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Xdebug Cloud",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "xdebugCloudToken": ""
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ],
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/www",
        "/app": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
    }
}
```

I also upgraded my PHP and Apache versions. I am using XAMPP.

I've followed the step by step instructions of installing Xdebug and watched YouTube tutorials but nothing seems to work: my variables, watch and call stack are empty and code does not debug.

Comment: You might need the port in the ini file `xdebug.client_port=9003`

Comment: @NigelRen That's a default port for Xdebug 3, no real need to redeclare it again.

Comment: *"xdebug.remote_enable=on"* That's Xdebug v2 parameter. It does nothing in Xdebug v3; even more -- it prints that *"Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guid"* message. **Make sure to check the upgrade guide** (Xdebug gave you the link to it , right?) and remove all those v2 params (convert them into v3)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xdebug 3, you can remove the Xdebug 2 config from your VS Code launch.json file. Not sure if that causes problems, but probably best to keep with what you have installed.
reference the Xdebug settings options here: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Ensure your php.ini configuration is setup to work with your http server, paying particular attention to

```
xdebug.client_host =  
xdebug.client_port = 
xdebug.discover_client_host = 
xdebug.idekey =
xdebug.mode =
xdebug.start_upon_error =
xdebug.start_with_request =
```

Always restart your server after any changes to php.ini file. Verify your settings using a phpinfo.php file
E.g.

```
<?php // filename phpinfo.php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

ensure that Xdebug is showing in the phpinfo report (use your browser [control]+F to find "xdebug" quickly when your phpinfo.php file loads)

Are you using breakpoints, and "Listen for Xdebug"?
What happens when you try "Built-in server"?

Outside of VS Code, do you get Xdebug info if you encounter an error in php? You can test that by writing some code that you know will cause an error, and load it in the browser to see if you're getting the Xdebug info.

Reference this section at the Xdebug site:
https://xdebug.org/docs/install#xdebug_info

In summary, it's difficult to say what could be wrong. It would be helpful if you post your PHP version and Server info.
When you load the phpinfo.php file, look for a line near the top, "Loaded Configuration File" and ensure whatever is shown there is the php.ini file that you're editing.

Good luck!